# Is it mandatory to declare dependency on global module in JBoss7+ / WildFly?

Tags: java, jboss, dependencies, wildfly, jboss-modules

I declared sample module as global in `standalone.xml` of WildFly like this

```
<global-modules>
            <module name="org.javassist" slot="main"/>
</global-modules>
```

and then I thought that it is now automatically accessible by any deployed Java app. 
I've deployed my Java app with user dynamic code definition ability. 
But when I try to enter and compile there Java code with `import org.javassist.*;` then I get an error `package org.javassist does not exist`.

Have I to declare dependency on this global module as well as on usual module in my app?